# Why calling PowerShell script in Windows service not working?

Tags: windows, powershell, service, command

I'm using PowerShell class of System.Management.Automation.dll in my Windows Service project. Here is the PowerShell code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-AppxPackage -Name xxx");
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject item in results)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        //print the result into a log file
    }
}
...some exception catching code
```

I put the PowerShell code in my Windows Service OnStart method, then start the service, but there is nothing printed in the log file and no exception. Then I put the code in the service's main() method, it worked just fine. I then put the code in a new Windows forms project and it worked also perfect. Something happened in the service and I don't know what it is.

Is the "Get-AppxPackage" command not available in a service? Or am I missing something when create the service? Any help,please. Thanks.

Comment: Most probably a permission problem. Your service is running under local system, I guess. Try to run it with your own user and see what result you get. See "Detailed description" here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx

Comment: That's it! I use "Get-AppxPackage -Name xxx -AllUsers(or my domain account)",and it worked. Thank you David. But how can I mark your reply as an answer?